# Get only parent class data entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

I have a few classes with child objects. When I retrieve and convert the data to JSON - for example to a class `DeviceType` - it returns the data from the related child entities as well. How can I avoid getting the data of the child entities without setting `Ignore` attribute or `ProxyCreationEnabled`? In some cases I need child class data as well.

See the code below: when I select data for `DeviceTypes` it returns `Devices` too. Now I'm using `Select` to get only the fields which I need but as the application grows it will be difficult to handle. Since I'm using dynamic type I can return it only as object.

```
public partial class DeviceType
{

    public DeviceType()
    {
        this.Devices = new HashSet<Devices >();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}

public override ICollection<DeviceType> Get()
{
    return DbContext.Set<DeviceType>().ToList().Select(x => new DeviceType
    {
       Id = x.Id,
       Name =  x.Name
    }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not EF that behaves like this, it is your JSON serializer (likely Newtonsoft.Json). The child data are *actually not there*, they are lazily loaded. The fact that this happens is actually a serious problem (not with Newtonsoft.Json but with how you consume the data). The Json serializer, unless instructed otherwise, will simply reflect over your class, find all its properties (including collections), traverse them and serialize everything it finds into JSON. So, even if the object you are working with actually contains the collection as a lazy collection which is loaded when first accessed, the JSON serializer *does* see it and will include it.

The reasoning of why it is a problem is detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34672915/4205470), please read it.

The way to solve the problem, in a few words, detailed in the link above: don't send your DB entities. Besides being a possible source of Select N+1 problems it is also an enormous security vulnerability. Use viewmodels instead and project your data into them:

```
public IEnumerable<ResultViewModel> GetData()
{
    return dbItemsAsQueryable.Select(item => new ResultViewModel
    {
        Id = item.Id,
        Name = item.Name,
        // other properties
    }).ToList();

}
```

By utilizing the backing store as an `IQueryable` you not only avoid Select N+1's (since the query will be translated to the appropriate Joins) but you also solve the security problem simply because what you do no select will not be there. In other words, you only expose data that you actually want to expose.